# Case Sensitive Strings

Tags: discussion, tags, rules

Since this isn't explicitly codified anywhere, and was sparked by [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30754997#30754997) surrounding my [recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84218/42963), I figured I'd bring it up here for consensus before modifying the tag.

Related:

- [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)
- [What's a string?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string)
- [What are string literals?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3593/what-are-string-literals)
- Things to avoid when writing challenges: [Adding unnecessary fluff](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/42963)

### The Question

When a challenge asks for a string, what should the default case-sensitivity be?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unless specified otherwise, strings are case-sensitive. More generally, unless specified otherwise, **strings are just sequences of characters with no semantics attached to any specific characters**.

This should also be the least surprising default for users who are not aware of this post.

I'd also urge challenge authors to think twice before making a challenge case-insensitive. We've done case insensitivity more than often enough, and most of the time it's a concern that's completely orthogonal to the actual task of the challenge, and it just adds extra code for handling the case-insensitivity which adds nothing at all to the answers. [Related reading.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/8478)

Comment: This answer hits the nail on the head. If you think about strings as sequence of bytes in a particular encoding, case-insensitivity makes no sense. While whether or not `"A" == "a"` could be questioned, no reasonable person would think `0x41 == 0x61`.

Comment: May you bold the "it just adds extra code" so at a glance it's clear what your stance is on this?